# Localization in Xcode not working. Changes in Main.strings aren't applied

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

[image: Here you can see files arranged inside project]

I'm trying to translate iOS application into three languages (English, Polish, Serbian). Currently it is in Slovene. But I have problems with localization. I have set localization in Project/Info for all languages. Now I have four Main.strings files for each language. I have inserted the appropriate translations for each language. The translations are for UI elements that are located in Storyboard. Before I ran my application I have edited scheme and set application language to Polish, but it did not translate the UI. It was still in Slovene. Did I forgot something ?

Comment: where have you arranged those files ??

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot where those files exactly located ?

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh ok, I've added the screenshot.

Comment: are you using main bundle ?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: if possible then share your github link

Comment: Sorry it's not, can you explain what do you mean with main bundle ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193702/discussion-between-ahemadabbas-vagh-and-moonwalker4z).

Comment: Did you change the app language properly?  you can try like this `UserDefaults.standard.set(["de"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")` set the language code as an array not as a string.